# What size screenshots should be used for IAPs ( In app purchases ) for Mac apps?

Tags: macos, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, screenshot

What dimensions should be used for IAP screenshots for Mac apps on iTunesconnect?

I have tried uploading PNG screenshots with:

```
2560 x 1600 px
640 x 920 px
```

to no avail... but the upload does not seem to be accepted... Can anyone advise which dimensions will be accepted? Apple specifies 640 x 920 but it does not upload and there is no error message.

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the official docs I found this:

> A screenshot of the product as it appears on the device. This
>   screenshot is used for Apple’s review only and is not displayed on the
>   App Store. Screenshots requirements are outlined below: 
>   iOS: at least 640 x 920 pixels. 
>   tvOS requires 1920 x1080 pixels.
>   **macOS  requires 1280 x 800 pixels.**

Source: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev84b80958f

Interesting enough I just tried with a 640px (width) by 920px (height) screenshot for Mac IAP and everything is fine. Make sure you have no alpha-channel, but this gives another error.

Comment: 640*920plxs is okay.

Comment: I've edited my screenshot taking from the emulator in Sketch and resized it to 640x920px but I still get the error.

Comment: This may not work despite what the docs say.  Taking an iPhone X screenshot from the simulator DOES NOT WORK for the purposes of adding a screenshot (even if you use the simulator screenshot feature which does not include the window chrome).

Comment: REFER TO THE REPLY BELOW

Answer (score 69):

I would like to add to the accepted answer because regurgitating the documentation does little to resolve actual problems.

After taking a screen shot of the app on my device for in app purchase review and it still didn't work, I did some investigating.

After you attempt to upload a screen shot and see the error to upload a valid size, you can open the browser inspector to see the error details. The image MUST be one of these dimensions: 
[accepted resolutions found in console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddOpt.png)

Something else I didn't realize is when taking screen shots with command-shift-4 on macbooks, when you hold it down for the drag you can see the actual dimensions of the screen shot you are taking, but for some reason it saves it as DOUBLE the size. I ended up taking a screen shot where the cross hairs of the screen shot say 320 x 480 resulting in a saved png of 640x960. It has to be one of the pre set sizes in order for image upload to accept it.

After banging my head on a wall for a couple hours I figured this out, so I hope this helps others .

Comment: It's double due to Retina.

Comment: This helped a lot, thank you. I got a cryptic GeoJSON problem whatever that means. Tried upload again and then it worked.

Comment: Why not pressing `cmd + s` to save the screenshot in iOS Simulator directly?

Comment: I can confirm that exactly 640x920 works. But documentation says "at least", which is not true. https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev84b80958f

Comment: You fixed my problem. Thanks for debugging the web page source to find that out.

Comment: Apple should definitely hire better front-end devs! I think @NikHammer-Ellis did better job than most of the devs there.

Comment: I filed a Feedback about the bad documentation. FB8932186 in case anyone wants to dupe it. And FB8932183 because as of 12/7/2020 it doesn't accept iPhone 12 Pro sized screenshots.

Answer (score 16):

Even though in Apple docs it says: "iOS requires at least 640 x 920 pixels.", larger screenshots actually don't work..

Long story short:

Took a screenshot from iPhone X simulator - didn't work.

Took a screenshot from **iPhone 6 simulator - it did work.**

Comment: This worked for me as well. This is some garbage implementation on Apple's part.

Comment: Although the OP is in regards to macos. My search for the image size on the iOS platform brought me here. For some odd reason it won't accept the simulator screenshots even though it meets the requirements as stated by Apple. After saving the same screenshots from my device and transferring over, it accepted the images, even though it was larger than 640 x 920

Comment: Thanks. Using an iPhone 8 simulator worked, but iPhone 11 failed.

Comment: I was able to get this to work by using the SE simulator, but the 12 simulator definitely did not work.  "shrug"

Answer (score 6):

The image sizes for IAP screenshots should be one of the following:

- 2732x2048
- 2048x2732
- 1280x800
- 1440x900
- 2880x1800
- 2560x1600
- 1920x1080
- 3840x2160
- 312x390
- 1136x640
- 1136x600
- 640x1136
- 640x1096
- 2436x1125
- 1125x2436
- 1024x1024
- 960x640
- 960x600
- 640x960
- 640x920
- 1024x768
- 1024x748
- 768x1024
- 768x1004
- 2048x1536
- 2048x1496
- 1536x2048
- 1536x2008
- 1334x750
- 750x1334
- 2224x1668
- 1668x2224
- 2208x1242
- 1242x2208

Comment: Although other answers may have been correct at time of writing, they are now out-of-date. App Store Connect accepted a screenshot saved directly from the iPhone X simulator (1125x2436 png) today (however it would not accept an iPhone 11 simulator screenshot of 828x1792).

Answer (score 3):

After reading the above answers I tried different combinations of screenshots from the iPhone 11 pro max simulator none of them worked.

I tried a screenshot from a device(iPhone 6), it worked like a charm in the first attempt.
here are the details:
dimension: 750x1334
size: 303kb
JPEG image

Answer (score 2):

You basically have to use the resolution of an iPhone screen such as 750 x 1334 pixels which belongs to the iPhone 6/7/8 (4.7-Inch Retina Display).

Here's a list of the acceptable iOS screenshot resolutions:
https://www.storemaven.com/academy/product-page-creative-requirements-guide/

Answer (score 1):

My iPhone 11 screenshots were 828x1792 which were not accepted, so I upscaled them to 1242x2688, which were accepted.

As of writing, the list of accepted screenshots is located at:
https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/reference/screenshot-specifications

> ## 6.7" Display
>
> - iPhone 14 Pro Max
>
> ### Screenshot size
>
> - 1290 x 2796 pixels
>   (portrait)
> - 2796 x 1290 pixels
>   (landscape)
>
> ### Requirement
>
> Required if app runs on iPhone
>
> ### Screenshot source
>
> Upload 6.7-inch screenshots
>
> ## 6.5" Display
>
> - iPhone 14 Plus
> - iPhone 13 Pro Max
> - iPhone 12 Pro Max
> - iPhone 11 Pro Max
> - iPhone 11
> - iPhone XS Max
> - iPhone XR
>
> ### Screenshot size
>
> - 1284 x 2778 pixels
>   (portrait)
> - 2778 x 1284 pixels
>   (landscape)
> - 1242 x 2688 pixels
>   (portrait)
> - 2688 x 1242 pixels
>   (landscape)
>
> ### Requirement
>
> Required if app runs on iPhone and 6.7-inch screenshots are not provided
>
> ### Screenshot source
>
> #### Default:
>
> Scaled 6.7-inch screenshots
>
> #### Alternative:
>
> Upload 6.5-inch screenshots
>
> ## 6.1" Display
>
> - iPhone 14 Pro
>
> ### Screenshot size
>
> - 1179 x 2556 pixels
>   (portrait)
> - 2556 x 1179 pixels
>   (landscape)
>
> ### Requirement
>
> Required if app runs on iPhone and 6.5 inch or 6.7-inch screenshots are not provided
>
> ### Screenshot source
>
> #### Default:
>
> Scaled 6.5-inch or 6.7-inch screenshots
>
> Scaled 6.5-inch when 6.5-inch and 6.7-inch screenshots are both uploaded
>
> #### Alternative:
>
> Upload 6.1-inch screenshots
>
> ## 5.8" Display
>
> - iPhone 14
> - iPhone 13 Pro
> - iPhone 13
> - iPhone 13 mini
> - iPhone 12 Pro
> - iPhone 12
> - iPhone 12 mini
> - iPhone 11 Pro
> - iPhone XS
> - iPhone X
>
> ### Screenshot size
>
> - 1170 x 2532 pixels
>   (portrait)
> - 2532 x 1170 pixels
>   (landscape)
> - 1125 x 2436 pixels
>   (portrait)
> - 2436 x 1125 pixels
>   (landscape)
> - 1080 x 2340 pixels
>   (portrait)
> - 2340 x 1080 pixels
>   (landscape)
>
> ### Requirement
>
> Required if app runs on iPhone and 6.5 inch or 6.7-inch screenshots are not provided
>
> ### Screenshot source
>
> #### Default:
>
> Scaled 6.5-inch or 6.7-inch screenshots
>
> Scaled 6.5-inch when 6.5-inch and 6.7-inch screenshots are both uploaded
>
> #### Alternative:
>
> Upload 5.8-inch screenshots
>
> ## 5.5" Display
>
> - iPhone 8 Plus
> - iPhone 7 Plus
> - iPhone 6s Plus
>
> ### Screenshot size
>
> - 1242 x 2208 pixels
>   (portrait)
> - 2208 x 1242 pixels
>   (landscape)
>
> ### Requirement
>
> Required if app runs on iPhone
>
> ### Screenshot source
>
> Upload 5.5-inch screenshots
>
> ## 4.7" Display
>
> - iPhone SE (3rd generation, 2nd generation)
> - iPhone 8
> - iPhone 7
> - iPhone 6s
> - iPhone 6
>
> ### Screenshot size
>
> - 750 x 1334 pixels
>   (portrait)
> - 1334 x 750 pixels
>   (landscape)
>
> ### Requirement
>
> Required if app runs on iPhone and 5.5-inch screenshots aren't provided
>
> ### Screenshot source
>
> #### Default:
>
> Scaled 5.5-inch screenshots
>
> #### Alternative:
>
> Upload 4.7-inch screenshots
>
> ## 4" Display
>
> - iPhone SE (1st generation)
>
> ### Screenshot size
>
> - 640 x 1096 pixels
>   (portrait without status bar)
> - 640 x 1136 pixels
>   (portrait with status bar)
> - 1136 x 600 pixels
>   (landscape without status bar)
> - 1136 x 640 pixels
>   (landscape with status bar)
>
> ### Requirement
>
> Required if app runs on iPhone and 5.5 or 4.7-inch screenshots aren't provided
>
> ### Screenshot source
>
> #### Default:
>
> Scaled 5.5 or 4.7-inch screenshots
>
> #### Alternative:
>
> Upload 4-inch screenshots
>
> ## 3.5" Display
>
> - iPhone 4s
>
> ### Screenshot size
>
> - 640 x 920 pixels
>   (portrait without status bar)
> - 640 x 960 pixels
>   (portrait with status bar)
> - 960 x 600 pixels
>   (landscape without status bar)
> - 960 x 640 pixels
>   (landscape with status bar)
>
> ### Requirement
>
> Required if app runs on iPhone and 5.5-inch iPhone screenshots aren't provided
>
> ### Screenshot source
>
> #### Default:
>
> Scaled 5.5-, 4.7-, or 4-inch screenshots
>
> #### Alternative:
>
> Upload 3.5-inch screenshots

Answer (score 0):

Use the **iPhone 14 Pro** simulator for the **IAP screenshot**.

On my older versions of Xcode I used the [iPhone 6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53951983/4833705) which worked great for the IAP screenshot. Now I'm using Xcode 14.2 and the iPhone 6 isn't available. When I went to `Add Additional Simulators` and tried to add the iPhone 6 it said `Incompatible Device`.

I took a wild guess and used the **iPhone 14 Pro** which is available in the drop down and **App Store Connect accepted it**.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this
If we take a screen shot from iPhone, it is exported as ".PNG," which will give error of any size.
But when I open that file in Finder and export it as it is, which will have the ".png" extension, it is working at any size. very strange!!